# Amazon SNSを使ってiOSアプリからプッシュ通知を送信したい

Tags: ios, push-notification

Amazon SNS を用いて iOS 端末へプッシュ通知を実現しようとしておりますが、
サーバレスでユーザ端末から別ユーザ端末に対して、プッシュ通知を送信することは可能なのでしょうか。

具体的に申し上げますと、
以下のURLを参考に、

◆Amazon SNS モバイルプッシュを使用するために必要な手順の概要
　https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-pseudo.html

STEP4まで進めましたが、
STEP5（メッセージをモバイルエンドポイントに発行する処理）を実際にSwift上で表現することが可能なのかで悩んでおります。

参考となるサンプルをいくつか確認しており、コンソールを使用して自分の iOS 端末へメッセージの直接的な送信は確認できましたが、
何れもプッシュ通知の送信処理をサーバサイドで実装しているケースしか見つからず、
エンドポイントに発行する処理をクライアント上（Swift）で構築しているケースが見当たりません。

どんなヒントでも頂戴できますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

環境
　Xcode 7.3
　iOS 9.1
　Swift 2.1